# Insert String values into 2d array/matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I have a string of 1s and 0s that I need to insert into a [4] by [4] matrix, that I can then use for other things.

This is my attempt at it:

```
b = '0110000101101000'

m = [[], [], [], []]
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        m[i].append(b[i * j])
```

But where I expected to get

`[['0', '1', '1', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '1'], ['0', '1', '1', '0'], ['1', '0', '0', '0']`

I got `[['0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '1', '1', '0'], ['0', '1', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '1']]`.

Could someone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd agree with @John Zwinck that you can easily figure it out but if you hate math simply do

```
counter = 0
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        m[i].append(b[counter])
        counter += 1 # keep track of the overall iterations
```

otherwise you have to find the starting row you are in (`i * columns`) and add the current column index

```
m[i].append(b[i * 4 + j]) # i * 4 gives the overall index of the 0th element of the current row
```

Answer (score 2):

Get paper and a pencil and write a table of what you have now vs what you want:

```
i j i*j desired
0 0  0  0
0 1  0  1
0 2  0  2
0 3  0  3
1 0  0  4
1 1  1  5
... up to i=3, j=3
```

Now you can see that `i * j` is not the correct index in `b`.  Can you see what the desired index formula is?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint: range(4) starts from 0 and ends at 3.
See the python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the rule to convert coordinates to index is `index = row * NRO_COLS + col`. You should use `i * 4 + j`.

Second, you can use list comprehension:

```
m = [[b[i * 4 + j] for j in range(4)] for i in range(4)]
```

then, it can be rewritten as:

```
m = [[b[i + j] for j in range(4)] for i in range(0, len(b), 4)]
```

or

```
m = [list(b[i:i+4]) for i in range(0, len(b), 4)]
```

another alternative is to use [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/), which is a great library, specially to handle multidimensional arrays

```
import numpy as np

m = np.array(list(b)).reshape(4,4)
```

or:

```
print(np.array(list(b)).reshape(4, -1))
print(np.array(list(b)).reshape(-1, 4))
```